# What is the difference between "Butterschmalz" and "Butterreinfett"?

Tags: german-to-english, vocabulary

Both "Butterschmalz" and "Butterreinfett", have similar meaning in Leo. I can't identify the difference.

Comment: Asked like this, this is not a question for this forum. You should first consult a reference book of merchandise knowledge where you can look up standard requirements for products to be sold under certain names, and when then there are language-related questions left, come back here to discuss them.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Could you please give an example of "a reference book of merchandise knowledge"? As you can see in my question, I have already referred Leo, which is a popular multilingual dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe "Butterreinfett" is the technical term with specific meaning while "Butterschmalz" is a common term.

Both denote a type of clarified butter where water, milk protein and lactose have been removed by (among others) heating and  centrifugation. "Butterreinfett" has at least 99.8% of fat.

The common term, "Butterschmalz", might have been coined in order to associate it with *Schmalz*=lard, (which it is not).

You are more likely to find "Butterreinfett" used on a list of ingredients (e.g. of chocolate) and "Butterschmalz" more likely find as a product name in a shop.